# How to check for watchkit delegate call while using simulators?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

Currently i am using the following watchkit delegates.. I need to check whether they are being called or not while using simulators.

```
-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext
{
    NSLog(@"REminders Array %@",applicationContext);


}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)userInfo{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Received userInfo Transferr");
        NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    });
}
```

but they are not getting called while using simulators it is working fine in iphone applications. Any idea how to work with these??

Comment: Why it is downvoted?? Heyy i am asking for a solution for which i am new and no sufficient tutorials are there..

Answer (score 0):

mmm your question is not very clear, as the steps to test your capabilities? in general these delegates are launched following a submission by

```
- (BOOL)updateApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

and

```
- (WCSessionUserInfoTransfer *)transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)userInfo
```

Then if you're working with the simulator you have to set debugging to make sure that it can debug both applications (again if it's your case).